# How to compare String with SELECT result?

Tags: android, string, select

I use the method

`rawQuery("select * from schedule where week = ? and firstweek < ? and lastweek > ?", new String[]{weekday})`

the position "?" is character string,but how to compare it with Select statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given query expects to have three parameters, add two more to String array:

```
new String[]{weekday, new Date(), new Date()}
```